# Change the color of the "Saved/Not Saved" color bar in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is it possible to change the color of the bars on the left of the screen that changes to `green` if the line is saved, `yellow` if not, etc.? I couldn't find one in the "Fonts and Colors" tab of the Options menu, or on MSDN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading through all of the entries in the options menu I found it haha

[image: Screenshot]